# Dismiss a navigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have viewcontroller, which is embedded into a navigationController. When i click the `UIBarButtonItem` in this viewController it will present a new navigationController modally. How can i dismiss this navigationController?

I've tried following, but does not work?

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
```